# How to restrict the user inputs to the choices in autocomplete?

Tags: android, autocomplete

I have created an auto complete text-view which picks up its data from a particular set of values. I want the user to be able to select only from the provided values and not to be able to go ahead with any other choice.

I have been looking for a feasible answer since long but didn't get my hands on any. Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

PS: please note that I have already tried out the obvious text change watcher methods etc and am looking for something more worthwhile. Thank you! :)

REQUESTED CODE : (the usual basic auto complete one)

```
   autoText.setAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,arr);
   autoText.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                tool = my_adapter.getItem(position).toString();
            }
        });
   autoText.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) 
{
    Intent i=new Intent(this,Home.class);
    startActivity(i);       
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
{
}

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) 
{
    Intent i=new Intent(.this,Home.class);
    startActivity(i);       
}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0)
{   }
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) 
{   }
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) 
{
    tool=null;
       // trying to capture the value of item selected in variable *tool*.
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? without your code its hard to know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Why not a spinner? In that case, you restrict to only select from those available options in the spinner?

Comment: @Calvin, the number of values are too large to fit the usability of a spinner.

Answer (score 0):

use digits tag in autocomplete view in xml..., or use inputType tag

Comment: Please don't leave vague answers. Be specific in your suggested solution.

Comment: exactly what you want to restrict??

Comment: I think the question is self explanatory in that regard. I am using auto complete text-view and i don't want my user to be able to write anything apart from the choices that appear in the auto complete.

Comment: Simple get entered text from AutocompletextView and check that is it contains in your array or not..

Comment: @Garima Tiwari this can be done by two ways 1) you can use Alert Dialog and list out all your item and select one choice.(Like spinner) and 2) you can check run time if user select such item that does not exist in the our list then show alert or error.

Answer (score 0):

Check this.But I am using Text watcher.I haven't tried it.You have to do it yourself and check for errors.

```
String[] YourArray={"foo","foo1","foo2"};
autoText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            boolean flag=true;

            for(int i=0;i<YourArray.length;i++)
            {
            if(YourArray[i].contains(text.getText().toString()))
            {
                flag=false;
            }

            }

            if(flag==false)
            {
                String a=text.getText().toString();

                String b=a.substring(0, s.length()-1);

                text.setText(b);//If the text input by user is not in the array, we undo the user input by removing last character from edit text.

            }


        }
```

Comment: Have you tried out this code yourself, because it seems to be throwing a lot of errors.

Comment: I just wanted to give an idea about how to implement your requirements.And its clear in my answer that I didn't tried it myself.You have to check for errors.Let me try it and will get back to  you soon.

Comment: I didn't mean to be offensive! Im just saying that I tried the above and it was throwing a couple of errors. I've just left it to that and put a filter for wrong inputs.